# Consume Mono value and use it to call another Mono

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

My code is structured this way -

```
Mono<Address> m1 = method1() // this call returns address
Mono<Boolean> m2 = method2() // this call uses ReactiveMongoTemplate and updates document in Mongo
```

I am trying to achieve this :

when method1() returns me the address, I need to consume it and call method2() to update the address in a MongoDB document. No Exceptions thrown as well. But I don't see any logs inside method2()

Code :

```
Mono<Object> m1 = method1().map(address -> method2(address));
```

Although method2() is invoked, the document update in MongoDB is not happening.

Answer (score 5):

Your code snippet is returning `Mono<Mono<Boolean>>`, so nothing is subscribing to the inner `Mono`.

You should probably [use the `Mono.flatMap` operator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) like this:

```
Mono<Boolean> m1 = method1().flatMap(address -> method2(address));
```

This operator will flatten the chain of operations.

Comment: You can shorten this by calling `Mono<Boolean> m1 = method1().flatMap(method2);`